# How to test a specific value in last row of dataframe (using -1)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice, ambiguous

I have a continually updating dataframe (minute by minute) with a new row appended every minute. I wish to undertake a conditional test on the last value in the dataframe in a specific column. I've been trying to use [-1:] to specify the last row and the ['columnname']. However this returns a series and then the error 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous...etc'.
How to refer to a value in the last row of a specific column and conditionally test it?

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = {'D' : (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
            'O' : (4, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1),
            'OS' : (6, 1, 2, 0, 6, 4),
            'MAC' : (3, 6, 8, 6, 7, 9)}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: the simplified dataframe]

then to test the last row and the 'MAC' column:

```
    if df[-1:]['MAC'] == 9:
        print('OK - It works now!')
```

returns a 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous...'
I've tried numerous formulations using at, iat, get_value, values, loc, iloc, index, 
The simplest formulation:

```
    df[-1:]['MAC']
```

returns a series (which includes the index and the actual value):

```
    5    9
    Name: MAC, dtype: int64
```

Surely this is a foolishly simple problem...(on my part)...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scalars is possible convert Series to numpy array and select last value:

```
if df['MAC'].values[-1:] == 9:
    print('OK - It works now!')
```

Or select by positions with `-1` for last row and [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column `MAC`:

```
if df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('MAC')] == 9:
    print('OK - It works now!')
```

Or select by labels by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - but necessary use last value of index:

```
if df.loc[df.index[-1], 'MAC'] == 9:
    print('OK - It works now!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
>>> df.iloc[-1]['MAC']
9
```

Comment: I think it seems good idea first, but if check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters) always is best avoid using `][` in pandas